# Walking through a NotesViewNavigator

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

I posted part of this previously but thought I would start a new thread with a more complete code and problem. I am trying to walk through the categories in a NotesViewNavigator and this is the code that I am using. I have stripped it down to pretty much a minimum. The WFSUtils.sysOut just writes a message to the server console. The view has the "Do Not Display Empty categories" checked.

```js
vw.setAutoUpdate(false);
var nav:NotesViewNavigator = vw.createViewNav();
nav.setEntryOptions(NotesViewNavigator.VN_ENTRYOPT_NOCOUNTDATA);
nav.setBufferMaxEntries(400);
nav.setMaxLevel(0);
var rtn:java.util.TreeMap=new java.util.TreeMap();
var entry:NotesViewEntry = nav.getFirst();
var thisCat:java.util.Vector = new java.util.Vector;
try{
while (entry != null){
    WFSUtils.sysOut("Entry not null");
    thisCat = entry.getColumnValues();
    var thisCatString = thisCat.elementAt(0).toString()
    WFSUtils.sysOut("thisCat = " + thisCatString);
    rtn.put(thisCatString,"Nothing");
    WFSUtils.sysOut("did put " + thisCatString)
    var tEntry:NotesViewEntry = nav.getNextCategory();
    entry.recycle();
    entry = tEntry;
    tEntry.recycle();
}
viewScope.put("vsCats", rtn.keySet());
}catch(e){
    WFSUtils.sysOut("Error in getCategory " + e.toString())
}
```

When I run this code I get the following in the server console.

```
25/08/2014 12:55:42 PM  HTTP JVM: Entry not null
25/08/2014 12:55:42 PM  HTTP JVM: thisCat = Approved~Bill Fox^WFS Automated Back end Process Example
25/08/2014 12:55:42 PM  HTTP JVM: did put Approved~Bill Fox^WFS Automated Back end Process Example
25/08/2014 12:55:42 PM  HTTP JVM: Error in getCategory Method NotesViewNavigator.getNextCategory(lotus.domino.local.ViewEntry) not found, or illegal parameters
```

It fails at the getNextCategory(entry) that it is not found or illegal parameter. If I change it to just getNext(entry) the console log shows:

```
25/08/2014 01:06:48 PM  HTTP JVM: Entry not null
25/08/2014 01:06:48 PM  HTTP JVM: thisCat = Approved~Bill Fox^WFS Automated Back end Process Example
25/08/2014 01:06:48 PM  HTTP JVM: did put Approved~Bill Fox^WFS Automated Back end Process Example
25/08/2014 01:06:48 PM  HTTP JVM: Entry not null
25/08/2014 01:06:48 PM  HTTP JVM: Error in getCategory Exception occurred calling method NotesViewEntry.getColumnValues()
25/08/2014 01:06:48 PM  HTTP JVM: null
```

So it would appear to me that the var entry is getting messed up somewhere along the line. Interesting is that the getFirst works and my code functions the way I would expect it but neither getNext nor getNextCategory seems to work. Am I missing something in my code or what the getNextCategory should be doing.

Comment: If you're only interested in getting a sorted list of categories, you might consider using a `TreeSet` instead of a `TreeMap`. Looks like you don't really need the map. And since the categories in a view are already sorted, you could also just use a `List`.

Comment: I thought of that but wanted to get it working first. Knut's answer fixed it for me, sometimes you can look so hard that you can't see.

Comment: @Mark did you write the Application Scope document locking for Xpages? I got a copy of it but the person who sent it to me could not remember where it came from. It kind of looks like some of your type of code. Also, if it is your code is there a place to download it?

Comment: That wasn't me. Might be this one: http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/XPage%20Document%20Locker

Comment: That does not appear to be it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the line

```
tEntry.recycle();
```

This recycle() destroys your `entry` as both `entry` and `tEntry` point to the same Notes object.

Delete the parameter from

```
... nav.getNextCategory();
```

Your code shown in question doesn't have a parameter but the error message and your comment tell you have.

Comment: I had already spotted the parameter in the getNextCategory but not the implications of thr tEntry.recycle. I now works the way It should so onward and upward. Thanks. Should have seen that.

Comment: It is always a good practice to show the code to someone else in such cases as an other person has a different look on code and often sees the issue right away simply because it's not the own code.

Comment: Got that right, but I'm sitting here alone. Thanks for your extra set off eyes.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant: to ask a question here on StackOverflow is part of the good practice to show the code to someone else :-) .

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have ended up with. What I need to do is create a series of nested Reapeat controls that function much like native Notes Categories. So the top level category is bound to a viewScope "vsCat1", the next to "vsCat2" and the last to "vsCat3" This process could be extended to handle more levels but I generally try to keep the number of categories below that. For this example the three categories are Status, Originator and Process. I have then built three views called vwDocsByStatus, vwDocsByStatusOrig, and vwDocsByStatusOrigProcess. The first column in each view is categorized. The byStatus view is simply a categorized view by Status, the StatusOrig is Status + "~" + Originator and the third Status + "~" + Originator + "~" + Process. 
The collection name for the first repeat is cat1, second cat2 and third cat3. My code below is a JavaScript function that I'm going to move to a JAVA Bean but the function would be the same. So to load "vsCat1" I would call setCategory("vwDocsByStatus",""), to load "vsCat2" I would call setCategory("vwDocsByStatusOrig", cat1) which would load vsCat2 with all of the categories under cat1. calling setCategory("vwDocsByStatusOrigProcess", cat1 + "~" + cat2) will load vsCat3 with all categories under the combination cat1 ~ cat2. The limitation is that there is no expand all type of action, but I have found that in most cases that is OK. 
Then in the final repeat it is bound to the domino view vwDocsByStatusOrigProcess and a computed filter on column of cat1 + "~" + cat2 + "~" + cat3 
Each repeat has an expand/collapse button that sets some viewScope variables to control visibility and calls setCategory with the appropriate view and cat values. Faster method is to just get the column values from a view but that does not take into account reader fields so the return might have some category values that the user is not allowed to see. My testing this far is that this is pretty fast. 
Hope this helps someone, also if you can see how to improve it feel free to make suggestions

```
function setCategory(appView:String , cat:String){
    /*Given a categorized view retrieve the a list of values and store that
     * list in a viewScope variable "vsCat" + n where n = "1" if cat is null
     * if cat contains one "~" n = 2 if cat conatins two "~" n = 3
     * 
     */
    //get appDB and the view
    try{
        var vw:NotesView = appProps[sessionScope.ssApplication].appDB.getView(appView);
        vw.setAutoUpdate(false);
        var nav:NotesViewNavigator = vw.createViewNav();
        nav.setEntryOptions(NotesViewNavigator.VN_ENTRYOPT_NOCOUNTDATA);
        nav.setBufferMaxEntries(400);
        nav.setMaxLevel(0);
    }catch(e){
        WFSUtils.sysOut("Error in setCategory - " + e.toString());
        return "";
        break;
    }
    try{
        var rtn:java.util.TreeSet=new java.util.TreeSet();
        var entry:NotesViewEntry = nav.getFirst();
        if (cat.indexOf("~") > 0) {
            n = 3;
        }else if (cat == null || cat == ""){
            n = 1;
        }else  {
            n = 2;
        }
        var catArray:Array = cat.split("~");
        var thisCat:Array = new Array;
        while (entry != null && !entry.isTotal()) {
            thisCat = entry.getColumnValues();
            var temp:String = thisCat[0].toString();
            thisCat = temp.split("~");
            if (typeof thisCat === "string"){
                thisCat = [thisCat];
            }
            switch (n){
                case 1 :
                        if (!rtn.contains(thisCat[0])){
                            rtn.add(thisCat[0]);
                        }

                    break;
                case 2 :
                    if (cat == thisCat[0]){
                        if (thisCat[1] != null){
                            if (!rtn.contains(thisCat[1]))rtn.add(thisCat[1]);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 3 :
                    if (cat == thisCat[0] + "~" + thisCat[1]){
                        if (thisCat[2] != null){
                            if (!rtn.contains(thisCat[2]))rtn.add(thisCat[2]);
                        }
                    }
                    break
            }

            var tmpentry:NotesViewEntry = nav.getNextCategory();
            entry.recycle();
           entry = tmpentry;
        }// end while
        // set the viewScope variable
        vw.setAutoUpdate(true);
        viewScope.put("vsCat" + n.toString(),rtn);
    }catch(e) {
        WFSUtils.sysOut("Error in setCategory - " + e.toString());
    }finally{
        try{
            WFSUtils.recycleObjects([nav, entry, tmpEntry]);
        }catch (e) {
            //do nothing caused by undefined object shouldn't happen
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `cat.indexOf("~") > 0` returns also true if it contains only one "~", e.g. "aaa~bbb".indexOf("~") would return 3.

Comment: Knut I removed some comments from my code and deleted the entry = tmpentry, edited it above. In my case there would never be more than one "~" in the cat string unless I extended it to go to 4 levels of category. So this works for my case but probably need to make that change because somewhere I will no doubt go to 4 levels. Never say never. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: I see. I was irritated by the comments in function header but after a longer look I see what do you want to achieve and you need to test for one "~" only. Looks good - good luck with your project.

Comment: I'm going to re-write this in JAVA in my Utils Bean and I will make it so that it is extensible to more than 3 levels, but for the moment this works fine. Thanks